# text out of the div is malformed

Tags: html, css

i have this code

```
<html lang='es'>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="theme.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap337/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap337/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap337/css/normalize.css">
        <script src="bootstrap337/js/jquery-3.2.0.min.js"></script>
        <script src="bootstrap337/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <style>
            * {
            padding:0.5%;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class='col-md-12' style='background-color:#DDD'>
        <h1 class='text-center'>Sea bienvenido a la web</h1><hr/>
        </div>
        <hr/>
        <div class='col-md-3' style='background-color:#DDD'>
        <p class='text-justify'>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin tincidunt dictum lacus sed pellentesque. Suspendisse dignissim eros eget lacus commodo, nec congue ante sollicitudin. Ut consequat metus at metus volutpat congue sit amet facilisis turpis. Fusce vitae eros lectus. Nullam blandit massa ac erat tempor fermentum. Aenean tristique eu neque at sagittis. Curabitur sed dui ut orci rutrum fringilla. Phasellus suscipit lacus ut iaculis interdum. Nunc vehicula lacus at risus luctus, non malesuada urna tempor. In eget massa ligula..</p>
        </div>
        <div class='col-md-6' style='background-color:#EEE'>
            <div class='col-md-6' style='background-color:#AAA'>
                <p class='text-justify'>Vivamus sit amet cursus diam, non aliquet urna. Mauris viverra commodo fringilla. Donec rutrum sodales ex a tincidunt.</p>
            </div>
        <p class='text-justify'>Nam ac fermentum nulla. Donec nibh lacus, feugiat vitae magna sit amet, mollis ornare lorem. Etiam a auctor enim. Nam sed egestas est. Vivamus sit amet cursus diam, non aliquet urna. Mauris viverra commodo fringilla. Donec rutrum sodales ex a tincidunt. Integer volutpat mauris eget dictum tristique. Suspendisse quis sagittis nisl. In purus lorem, volutpat in eros cursus, porta faucibus ligula. Sed non dolor convallis, efficitur urna a, congue velit. Pellentesque nec ante sit amet leo ultricies fringilla efficitur sit amet est. Proin ut ullamcorper felis. Quisque eget iaculis arcu.</p>
        </div>
        <div class='col-md-3' style='background-color:#DDD'>
        <p class='text-justify'>Nunc suscipit augue iaculis, facilisis ex a, tristique tellus. Nullam vel tellus libero. Nulla facilisi. Suspendisse potenti. Mauris in varius diam. Aliquam non malesuada tellus. Nullam pulvinar tellus id aliquet fermentum. Quisque sed dictum justo, id mollis ante. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Donec eu nisi facilisis metus porta consectetur id id nisi.</p>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

But the problem is the following: i want the text outside the div (thereis a div inside a div)
mid div dont get right text padding, as i mark in the image

How to solve the text right padding?

[Image with the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Somzk.png)

Comment: Your question doesn't appear to be clear. What text, what div?

Comment: text on the mid div dont have padding with the inside div, then, The text is stuck to the insider div

Comment: more explained image: [Image better explained](http://i.imgur.com/76IC6Ee.png)

Comment: What is the 'mid div'?

Comment: @Pineda it's the div marked in the image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give that element a right/bottom margin.

```css
.in-text-block {
  margin: 0 1em 1em 0;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<html lang='es'>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="theme.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap337/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap337/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap337/css/normalize.css">
  <script src="bootstrap337/js/jquery-3.2.0.min.js"></script>
  <script src="bootstrap337/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <style>
    * {
            padding:0.5%;
            }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class='col-md-12' style='background-color:#DDD'>
    <h1 class='text-center'>Sea bienvenido a la web</h1>
    <hr/>
  </div>
  <hr/>
  <div class='col-md-3' style='background-color:#DDD'>
    <p class='text-justify'>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin tincidunt dictum lacus sed pellentesque. Suspendisse dignissim eros eget lacus commodo, nec congue ante sollicitudin. Ut consequat metus at metus volutpat congue sit amet facilisis turpis.
      Fusce vitae eros lectus. Nullam blandit massa ac erat tempor fermentum. Aenean tristique eu neque at sagittis. Curabitur sed dui ut orci rutrum fringilla. Phasellus suscipit lacus ut iaculis interdum. Nunc vehicula lacus at risus luctus, non malesuada
      urna tempor. In eget massa ligula..</p>
  </div>
  <div class='col-md-6' style='background-color:#EEE'>
    <div class='col-md-6 in-text-block' style='background-color:#AAA;'>
      <p class='text-justify'>Vivamus sit amet cursus diam, non aliquet urna. Mauris viverra commodo fringilla. Donec rutrum sodales ex a tincidunt.</p>
    </div>
    <p class='text-justify'>Nam ac fermentum nulla. Donec nibh lacus, feugiat vitae magna sit amet, mollis ornare lorem. Etiam a auctor enim. Nam sed egestas est. Vivamus sit amet cursus diam, non aliquet urna. Mauris viverra commodo fringilla. Donec rutrum sodales ex a tincidunt.
      Integer volutpat mauris eget dictum tristique. Suspendisse quis sagittis nisl. In purus lorem, volutpat in eros cursus, porta faucibus ligula. Sed non dolor convallis, efficitur urna a, congue velit. Pellentesque nec ante sit amet leo ultricies
      fringilla efficitur sit amet est. Proin ut ullamcorper felis. Quisque eget iaculis arcu.</p>
  </div>
  <div class='col-md-3' style='background-color:#DDD'>
    <p class='text-justify'>Nunc suscipit augue iaculis, facilisis ex a, tristique tellus. Nullam vel tellus libero. Nulla facilisi. Suspendisse potenti. Mauris in varius diam. Aliquam non malesuada tellus. Nullam pulvinar tellus id aliquet fermentum. Quisque sed dictum justo,
      id mollis ante. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Donec eu nisi facilisis metus porta consectetur id id nisi.</p>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Perfect!, that margin solves the problem, Many thanks!

Comment: @venadHD welcome to SO btw. Be sure to upvote any answers that helped out, and accept the best one as the solution (with the checkmark by answers) once the issue has been resolved.

Comment: Dont worry, i upvoted you ! :P, but with less than 15 rep is no publicly showing

Answer (score 0):

You have a lot of problems in your code.

Using bootstrap you should always put everything in a "container".

Then inside the container have a "row", then inside rows you have a "column".

example:

`<div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
         Some text
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>`

If you want to add more rows and coloumns you still have to keep it "in order" and always only put columns inside of rows and rows inside of columns (or inside containers).

This will make your page work better because in Bootstrap there are paddings and margins that even each other out.

Then if you want to add padding to a specific div, it's better not to override the bootstrap classes, nor add padding to * which effects everything.

Instead- add a class to the div you want to add padding to and add padding for that class only.

example

```
`<style>
 .extra-padding {
   padding: 20px;
  }
 </style>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
     <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-3">
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-9 extra-padding">
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>`
```